# Indexing numpy 2D array that wraps around

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

How do you index a numpy array that wraps around when its out of bounds?

For example, I have 3x3 array:

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]])

## 
[[ 1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10]
 [11 12 13 14 15]]
```

Say I would like to index the values around index (2,4) where value `15` is located.  I would like to get back the array with values:

```
[[9,  10, 6]
 [14, 15, 11]
 [4,  5,  1]]
```

Basically all the values around 15 was returned, assuming it wraps around

Comment: look at np.take

Comment: @hpaulj something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65398035/237105)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can do it without padding. This can generalize easily to when you want more than just one neighbor and without the overhead of padding the array.

```
def get_wrapped(matrix, i, j):
  m, n = matrix.shape
  rows = [(i-1) % m, i, (i+1) % m]
  cols = [(j-1) % n, j, (j+1) % n]
  return matrix[rows][:, cols]

res = get_wrapped(matrix, 2, 4)
```

---

Let me explain what's happening here `return matrix[rows][:, cols]`. This is really two operations.

The first is `matrix[rows]` which is short hand for `matrix[rows, :]` which means give me the selected rows, and all columns for those rows.

Then next we do `[:, cols]` which means give me all the rows and the selected cols.

Comment: I see, this is actually very adaptable where if i want 2 neighbors i can just add 2 elements in the row and col list with a -2 and a +2.  The only thing Im a little confuse about is whats the : for matrix[rows][:, cols].  I would think its just for matrix[rows][cols] but obviously that doesnt work.

Comment: So in numpy you can index into matrices using matrix[row, col] instead of pythons list[row][col]. So what that is doing is really two separate indexings `a = matrix[rows]` and `b = a[:, cols]`. The `:` just means all.

Comment: Ah right, that makes a lot of sense.  Thank you for the explanation

Comment: Each '[]` is evaluated (by the Python interpreter) individually.  `matrix[rows]` is done, then `[cols]` on the result.  So you have to pay attention to the intermediate result.  In `[rows, cols]` `numpy` handles both parts together.

Answer (score 6):

A fairly standard idiom to find the neighboring elements in a `numpy` array is `arr[x-1:x+2, y-1:y+2]`.  However, since you want to wrap, you can pad your array using wrap mode, and offset your `x` and `y` coordinates to account for this padding.

This answer assumes that you want the neighbors of the first occurence of your desired element.

---

First, find the indices of your element, and offset to account for padding:

```
x, y = np.unravel_index((m==15).argmax(), m.shape)
x += 1; y += 1
```

Now `pad`, and index your array to get your neighbors:

```
t = np.pad(m, 1, mode='wrap')    
out = t[x-1:x+2, y-1:y+2]
```

```
array([[ 9, 10,  6],
       [14, 15, 11],
       [ 4,  5,  1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

The `take` function works in-place.

```
>>> a = np.arange(1, 16).reshape(3,5)
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])
>>> b = np.take(a, [3,4,5], axis=1, mode='wrap')
array([[ 4,  5,  1],
       [ 9, 10,  6],
       [14, 15, 11]])
>>> np.take(b, [1,2,3], mode='wrap', axis=0)
array([[ 9, 10,  6],
       [14, 15, 11],
       [ 4,  5,  1]])
```